# How do you add a language in glibc.git if the ISO 639-2 code does not exist for it?

Tags: language-support, launchpad, translation

I want to add translations for Colognian (https://translations.launchpad.net/+languages/ksh) in the Ubuntu Launchpad. For this, I have to create an Ubuntu translation team. In order to do this, I have to add it to glibc.git, but:

> Choose the name of the locale. The format is language_REGION@modifier, where language is an ISO 639-2 two-letter code (or the three-letter one if the former is not available), ...

for Colognian there is sadly no ISO 639-2 code avaliable, the one you find on Wikipedia (gem) is reserved for Germanic languages.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can create the `ubuntu-l10n-ksh` team right now, if you like. This is the general guidance for starting a translations team:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Translations/KnowledgeBase/StartingTeam

But translations into Colognian won't be possible to make use of without a matching locale. A new locale, e.g. `ksh_DE.UTF-8` or `de_DE.UTF-8@ksh` would need to be added to glibc. A request for the creation of such a locale can be submitted here:

https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/enter_bug.cgi?product=glibc&component=localedata

But now is the time to give you a hint on how much work is involved in creating a new language. Much of what I want to say about that is summarized in this list message:

https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-translators/2023-May/007890.html

So my primary advice would be: Please read that message carefully before you proceed with establishing Colognian as a FOSS language.